# Resetting Loader from CursorAdapter or some otherway to work around this?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have custom CursorAdapter where I have set ut a deletebutton in the overrided bindView function. Below is the code for that and the deletePhrase(id, context) is just a function that uses the provides delete function. I tried lots of different stuff make this button seperatly from the onClick for the listitem, cause when I added the button orinally it made the onclick for the item itself not function so I made the textView clickable instead, my point being that I might have got lost somewhere along the way and there's a much better way to do this.

```
    Button delButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_removeButton);


    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    delButton.setTag(id);

    delButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int rowId = (Integer) v.getTag();
            long ret = deletePhrase(rowId, v.getContext());
            if (ret > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

But now here's my issue I want to reset the Loader which I have implemented in the fragment that displays the list. Now in that fragment I have a button to add a phrase which at the end calls this:

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
```

So when I add a phrase it will update the UI accordingly but I can't seem to get the same functionality for when I delete since I do this from the CursorAdapter class from which I can't seem to get access to the loader. Im flexible to any solutions that might work. Maybe there's someway I can move my deletePhrase function to the fragment and call it from there but then I'd have to get the correct instance of the fragment into the CursorAdapter class? Sorry I don't really know im kinda new to android and programming in general.

Comment: Are you using the ContentProvider too? if so there is no need to call restartLoader ContentResolver.delete would be enough ..

Comment: I am using Content provider, in the delete function in the content provider I  do this at the end:

getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);

Which I thought was gonna do just that, but it doesn't seem to work. Im not sure what Im missing.

Comment: Sorry I meant this:
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

Comment: in `query` of the `ContentProvider` implementation you should add `cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);` before you return the cursor .... and in update/insert/update you should add `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` ... now every call of insert/update/delete will cause cursor to be reloaded autmagically with Loader API :) (with the same uri of course)

Comment: That did it, thanks alot. I thought it was weird, cause that's what I figured was one of the points of using a Loader in the first place. Cheers!